# Difference between community and Enterprise Magento 2 extensions?

Tags: magento2, extensions

What are differences between Magento 2 Community and Enterprise extensions? I am aware that there is absolutely no difference for Magento 1. But is it the same also with Magento 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In General Term There is no difference between Magento2CE and Magento2EE extension.**

Even though When we see on the coding side there is no logical/code wise difference between **M2CE(Magento Open Source) And M2EE(Magento Commerce).**

> **But as we know Magento Enterprise Edition have extra module/features so any third party extension which is depended on Default Enterprise
>   edition module/functionality then you must required to purchase
>   Enterprise Edition Extension**

**Note :** Another possibility is depends on extension developer - sometimes they develop such kind of functionality where they detect which magento version are you using community or enterprise , that time you must go with the used Magento version extension.Otherwise it generates compatibility error and change of possibility to stop extension functionality as well

**Otherwise both are same**

Comment: So, I assume not code change with all edition either Magento Open Source or Magento Commerce prem or Magento Commerce cloud.  and I can sell with all in the marketplace, right?